# ECSlidingViewController property not found?

Tags: ios, xcode, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to use ECSlidingViewController in my app and have run into an issue while trying to use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqFFjmhoO1c.
I am trying to access the "underleftwidthlayout" function and its saying it doesnt exist even though I am able to use self.slidingviewcontroller. I dont understand why this would be happening. here is the code. 
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Main",@"Second", nil];
[self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:200.0f];
self.slidingViewController.underleftWidthLayout = ECfullwidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ECRight` turned to `anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:onComplete`

`ECLeft` turned to `anchorTopViewToLeftAnimated:onComplete`

`resetTopview` to `resetTopViewAnimated:onComplete`

and instead of importing `"ECSlidingViewController.h"` import : `"UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController.h"`

Comment: you need to clarify what you are saying in more details and also try to put the code which can be compiled!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you forgot to add "#import "ECSlidingViewController.h" into the .m file?

Answer (score 0):

The first step you should have done is look in the `ECSlidingViewController.h` and you would have seen that the property doesn't exist there.

The tutorial you are viewing is pretty old (1 year is really old in the programming world). The `underleftWidthLayout` property has been removed long ago, in a commit made on  Oct 27, 2013.